# Upgrade rails applications from rails 2.3.8 to 3 on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Anyone can provide links to upgrade my rails application from rails 2.3.8 to 3 on my windows machine ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a few links:

- Railscasts [#225](http://railscasts.com/episodes/225-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-1), [#226](http://railscasts.com/episodes/226-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-2), [#227](http://railscasts.com/episodes/227-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-3)
- [Make your Rails 2.3 project more Rails 3 oriented](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/07/the-way-to-rails-3/)
- [Rails Links & Resources](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2010/8/28/rails-has-great-documentation)
- [Upgrading from Rails 2 to Rails 3](http://thinkcode.tv/catalog/upgrading-rails-3/) ($8.99)
- [Peepcode Rails 3 Upgrade Handbook](http://peepcode.com/products/rails-3-upgrade-handbook-pdf) ($12.00)

Answer (score 0):

Try [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/). Episodes #225, #226 and #227 are all focused on upgrading (although done in OS X, most tips should be the same).